# Finding difference between keyed vectors of different lengths (in matlab)

Tags: matlab, union

I have two (key, value) pairs:

```
key_1 = {'a','b','c','d'};
val_1 = [1 2 5 -1]; 

key_2 = {'a','c','b','e','f','g'};
val_2 = [1 2 5 -8 2 0];
```

I would like to find a resulting value that takes the element-wise difference between the two values while preserving the ordering of the keys. Further, if a key is not present in either 1 or 2, then, the value can be taken to be zero.

It might make sense to first find the union of the two keys (in some sorted order):

```
key_result = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g'};
```

then, the resulting element-wise difference (i.e., `value_2 - value_1`) w.r.t. this new key would be:

```
val_result = [0 3 -3 1 -8 2 0];
```

I would appreciate an efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key functions to solve this problem are [`union`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.union.html) and [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```matlab
key_1 = {'a','b','c','d'};
val_1 = [1 2 5 -1]; 

key_2 = {'a','c','b','e','f','g'};
val_2 = [1 2 5 -8 2 0]; 

% These are all the keys, in alphabetical order
keys = union(key_1, key_2)

% This array will be filled with the difference
val_diff = zeros(size(keys));

% Step 1: add the values of set 1
[~,ii] = ismember(key_1,keys);
val_diff(ii) = val_1;

% Step 2: subtract the values of set 2
[~,ii] = ismember(key_2,keys);
val_diff(ii) = val_diff(ii) - val_2;
```

The second output argument of `ismember(a,b)` is the index of each element of `a` in the array `b`. The first output argument we ignore, it is true for each member of `a` because of how we constructed `b` above.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [`accumarray`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html?requestedDomain=). The idea is to apply `accumarray` with a minus in front of the values you want to subtract. This could have been applied directly if your keys were integers

```
key_1 = 1:4;
val_1 = [1 2 5 -1]; 

key_2 = [1,3,2,5,6,7];
val_2 = [1 2 5 -8 2 0]; 

val_diff = accumarray([key_1,key_2],[-val_1,val_2]) %note the minus in front of val_1
```

However, as they are not we will first have to convert to integers, which can e.g. be done with

```
key = {'a','b','c','d'};
nkey = cellfun(@(x)x-96,key) %The ascii number of a = 97, b=98 etc.
```